# How to Extract HTML Source Code using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

Certain URL of a website I try to extract the HTML off does not work.
Other ones do work.

I tried the posted code as well as varients of it. However I did not get it to work for this URL: https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_genomemap?ORG=vph&ACCESSION=VPUCM_0536

The Same code works perfectly fine for this URL from the same website:
https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_organism?org=T03116

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False: .Send
        getHTTP = .responseBody
    End With
End Function
```

No actual HTML code is being shown, only a #VALUE error. When I MsgBox the concent of getHTTP, it does show the first 2500 characters of the HTML source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off using :

```
getHTTP = .responseText
```

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest), the `.responseBody` property:

> Retrieves the response entity body as an array of unsigned bytes.

While the `.responseText` property:

> Retrieves the response entity body as text.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try that.
I also read somewhere else. that 1 excel cell can not contain more then 65000 characters. Maybe that was a problem.